# Rails 4 link_to method: :post and remote: true strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs, link-to-remote

I have an event management page which contains two partials, one with the partners not yet invited to the event, one with the partners invited to the event. Partners can either be added to the event (other_partners collection) or be removed (current_partners collection).

> Strange behavior depending on order of actions

**Delete then create => Everything is ok, I can add and remove with no limit**

Once the page loaded, I can remove partner (method: :delete) whithout any problem, partner disappear from current_partners collection (partial) and appears in other_partners collection (partial). If a try to add a partner, it works and the partner is added to current_partners collection and removed from other_partners collection

**Create then GET 500 ERROR => Rails seems to ignore ujs**

Once the page loaded, If I click on a partner inside other_partner partial to add (method: :post) it to the event, rails ignores the `method: :post` and GET the url provided, which causes a 500 error because the action show is not present inside my controller (only create and destroy)

**Here is my code :**

_other_partner.html.erb

is a partial containing user's partners that don't participate to the event. On click on a partner, it is added to the event, disappear form the other_partners collection and appears in the current_partners collection.

Note that the url looks like /events/1/manage_partners?id=21.
I'm passing the id of partner as additional param to create the link between event and partner. I'm not using button because partials already are inside a larger form.

```
  <%= div_for partner, class: "partner__current",
                       data: { behavior: "partner", id: partner.id } do %>

    <%= link_to event_manage_partners_path(event, id: partner.id),
                method: :post,
                data: { behavior: "create-partner" },
                remote: true,
                class: "link--primary" do %>
        <%= content_tag :div, nil, class: "icon icon__add_circle--black" %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

-

_current_partner.html.erb

is a partial listing all the partners that participates to the event. On click on a partner, it is deleted from the event, disappear from the current_partners collection and appears in the other_partners collection.

```
  <%= div_for partner, class: "partner__current",
                       data: { behavior: "partner" } do %>

    <%= link_to event_manage_partner_path(event, partner),
                method: :delete,
                remote: true,
                class: "link--primary" do %>
        <%= content_tag :div, nil, class: "icon icon__cancel_circle--black" %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

-

event.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'partners/other_partner',
                     collection: @event_facade.other_partners,
                     as: :partner,
                     locals: { event: @event_facade.event },
                     cached: true %>
<% end %>

<%= render partial: 'partners/current_partner',
                     collection: @event_facade.current_partners,
                     as: :partner,
                     locals: { event: @event_facade.event },
                     cached: true %>
<% end %>
```

-

create.js and destroy.js (both are similar)

```
$("[data-behavior='new-partner']").html("<%= j render partial: 'partners/other_partner', collection: @event_facade.other_partners, as: :partner, locals: { event: @event_facade.event }, cached: true %>");

$("[data-behavior='current-partners']").html("<%= j render partial: 'partners/current_partner', collection: @event_facade.current_partners, as: :partner, locals: { event: @event_facade.event }, cached: true %>");
```

-

events/manage_partner_controller.rb

```
module Events
  class ManagePartnersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_event

    def create # (url looks like /events/1/manage_partners?id=21)
      @event_facade = EventFacade.new(@event)
      EventPartnerService.new(@event).join_event(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to edit_event_url(@event) }
        format.js # { render layout: false }
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @event_facade = EventFacade.new(@event)
      EventPartnerService.new(@event).leave_event(params[:id], current_user)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to edit_event_url(@event) }
        format.js # { render layout: false }
      end
    end

    private

    def set_event
      @event = current_user.events.find(params[:event_id])
    end

  end
end
```

-

layout/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

-

assets/javascript/application.js (jquery-ujs loaded by bower)

```
//= require jquery/dist/jquery.min
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//
//= require jquery-ujs/src/rails
//= require turbolinks
```

-

routes.rb

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show], concerns: :paginatable do
  resources :events, except: :new, concerns: :paginatable do
    resources :manage_partners, controller: 'events/manage_partners', only:[:create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

-

rake routes output

```
event_manage_partners POST (/:locale)/events/:event_id/manage_partners(.:format) events/manage_partners#create {:locale=>/en-US|fr-FR/}

event_manage_partner DELETE (/:locale)/events/:event_id/manage_partners/:id(.:format) events/manage_partners#destroy {:locale=>/en-US|fr-FR/}
```

Here is the 500 error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/events/81/manage_partners"):
```

Rails tries to GET when I specifically ask for POST. The manage_partners_controller.rb doesn't contain an show action, only #create and #destroy, thus the error.

Again, everything works fine except the `method: :post` which is ignored when the link is clicked just after first page load.
Strange behavior, and I'm pretty clueless here. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You have listed everything but the error you are getting.

Comment: You right, I add it to the question

Comment: Lets see your routes.rb for that route.

Comment: Also, i've never see `//= require jquery-ujs/src/rails` before. It is usually just `//= require jquery-ujs`

Comment: Is Javascript enabled in your browser? cookies?

Comment: jquery-ujs is inside vendor/assets/components/jquery-ujs/src/rails.js file. But using //= require jquery-ujs produces the same error. Yes, cookie and javascript enable (and the delete action with remote true is processed as JS)

Comment: I add the routes to the original post

Comment: I would like to help, but there is too much to read in your question :(

Comment: It"s a little wordy I agree. Basically, once the page loaded, links with ujs work fine with delete method but fails with post method. That's pretty strange because if I click on delete first, then post method will work...

Comment: So on first load, if you post instead of delete, does that work? if it does, does the delete then fail w/o reloading page?

Comment: If i delete then post it works fine, if I post first then rails do get.
I do not know if it's the partial reload of the other_partners (those with post#create links) that occurs after deleting that make the post links work. What's really bother me is the fact that deleting work and post not, that's really misleading

Comment: Look ok. Added to original post

Answer (score 0):

Could be cause you are nesting a level too deep, you shouldn't nest resources more then one level deep. Take a look at this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Put this in the header of my page which solved issues with turbolink

```
  if(typeof Turbolinks != 'undefined') {
    $(document).on("page:change", function(){
      myFunction();
    });
  }
  else {
    $(document).ready(function (){
      myFunction();
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: I experimented a little with jquery-ujs, trying different combinations (with gem, with bower, with and without forms, require tree etc). It seems that there is something that makes turbolinks+bower jquery-ujs+require tree in /assets/javascript/application.js breaking things. Still digging

Comment: I've had an issue with turbolinks and jquery before, ill update my comment with what fixed it for me . might help guide yo etc

Comment: Ok, so I reinstalled all bower and components, clean slate. Now when I delete the require_tree . from application.js manifest file, it works. When I let it, it fails. I must have a file that fails silently, and I do not know how to identify it other than activate/deactivate (commenting the //= require ...) each one by one.

Comment: You might be calling the javascript twice, from 2 seperate places which might override.

Comment: I double-checked but that not seems to be the case. However, I checked everything and updated everything. As soon as I use require_tree ., post method is ignored at first load. I'll stick to declare all the requires manually for now, but It bothers me not knowing why it breaks.